# Stop "dd" inside a while loop after seconds

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I cant figure out how to do it, what i need is after "c" seconds, dd stops. But it keeps working and ignore both the while loops and the seconds
The script

```
read c
end=$((SECONDS+$c))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
    echo "Moving..."
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null 

done
```

Comment: You could do something like `timeout "$c" dd if=/dev/zero of/dev/null` instead of your loop. But what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better approach altogether.

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted, i didnt knew that timeout existed, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer for completeness:

To stop a process after a given amount of time, you can run it using [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) if your system provides it; it is part of the GNU coreutils (but apparently not specified by POSIX).

In your case, instead of your loop, you could run

```
timeout "$c" dd if=/dev/zero of/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how loops work.  Your construction will run until `dd` completes.  If you want to terminate it after c seconds, you should either invoke it with `timeout` (almost certainly the preferred solution), or send it a signal explicitly.  eg, something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
sleep $c
kill $!
```

Using `&` as the command terminator causes `dd` to be run asynchronously (aka "in the background"), so control returns immediately to the shell, storing the pid of the `dd` command in the variable `$!`.  The shell then sleeps for a bit and sends a signal to terminate `dd`.